# How many way can 3 distinct letter and 2 distinct digit be arranged if the digit must be together

Tags: permutations

Hi mind helping me out for this question ?

How many way can 3 distinct letter and 2 distinct digit be arranged  if the digit must be together.

Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the $2$ digits as _one_ distinct grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i manage to  figure it out .

Let A be digit  and B be letter .

Since there is 2  distinct digit and 3 distinct Letter the arrangement os

A A B B B
B B B A A
B A A B B
B B A A B

therefor is 3!*2! * 4 = 48.

And 48 was the book answer. so is my working right ?

Thanks For ur help :)

Comment: Your work is correct.  We can consider the block of two digits to be one object, giving us four objects to arrange.  There are $4! = 24$ ways to arrange four objects (the three letters and the block of two digits) and $2!$ ways to arrange the numbers within the block, giving $4!2! = 48$ possible arrangements.  It looks like you opted to arrange the three letters in $3!$ ways, arrange the two digits in $2!$ ways, and choose which of the four positions consists of the block of digits, which yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If the two digits must be together, replace them with a *fourth* letter and calculate the number of permutations. Then multiply the result by a number of permutations of digits 'inside the fourth letter'.

Answer (score 0):

Take 5 gaps. If the digits must be together, put two gaps in a box. There will be 4 ways this box can be selected. (You can check and see). Now you have 10 numbers and have to select 2 of them and arrange them. This can be done in $\binom{10}{2}2!$ ways. Then you have 26 letters and have to select 3 and then arrange them. This can be done in $\binom{26}{3}3!$. Therefore, the final answer should be $$4\binom{10}{2}2!\binom{26}{3}3!$$.